# Polymer JS: Does prepending an item to an Array property re-render the whole UI?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, html-rendering

I have a component with following template markup inside it

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{values}}">
    <div><span>{{item.msg}}</span></div>
</template>
```

This component has a property values which is an Array of objects.

Now  I want to prepend item to this array property in response to an event. Does polymer rerender this complete UI throwing away the existing DOM elements, because all the existing elements will pushed down by an index of 1 ? If so, what are optimizations I can implements to avoid DOM rerendering which can be expensive when the Array grows big.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is no.

It's not about `Polymer`, it's about `dom-repeat`.

About `dom-repeat` behavior, you can see from [github](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/lib/elements/dom-repeat.html).

In simple words for every render

- Create index array to apply sort and filter function
- Loop through the array of instance (an object from templatize function), assign an item to it if already exist (from previous render)
- If not, create a new one, push to array and insert to parent node.
- If it has exceeded instances, remove it.

See [`__applyFullRefresh`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/lib/elements/dom-repeat.html#L519).

So yes it reuse existing DOM elements.

As I said this is about `dom-repeat`. You should see [`iron-list`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-list) which do similar thing with better performance or create by yourself in the way you want.

Comment: `iron-list` will perform better for large data sets, specifically because it implements virtual scrolling (i.e. it only renders enough nodes to fill their container and then some for pre-caching to handle scrolling).